# Cast rowversion to bigint

Tags: sql-server

In my C# program I don't want to work with byte array, therefore I cast rowversion data type to bigint:

```
SELECT CAST([version] AS BIGINT) FROM [dbo].[mytable]
```

So I receive a number instead of byte array. Is this conversion always successful and are there any possible problems with it? If so, in which data type should I cast rowversion instead?

Comment: FYI: microsoft data conversion chart do not provide any information about this conversion: [link](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35834)

Comment: ROWVERSION and TIMESTAMP are synonyms, so microsoft data conversion chart allows implicit conversion from ROWVERSION to BIGINT and vise versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rowversion` and `bigint` both take 8 bytes so casting seems possible. However, the difference is that bigint is a signed integer, while rowversion is not.

This is a max value of rowversion that will cast properly to max positive bigint number (9223372036854775807):

`select cast(0x7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF as bigint)`

But starting from here, you'll be getting negative numbers:

`select cast(0x8000000000000000 as bigint)`

I didn't check if the latter cast throws an error in C#.

You problably won't reach more than 9223372036854775807 rows in your table, but still it's something you should know about, and I personally wouldn't recommend doing this unless you are certain that this problem will never occur in your solution.

Comment: rowversion should be unique across all tables in a database so the max # of rows concern is not for a specific table but for all rows in all tables in the database

Answer (score 3):

You can convert in C# also, but if you want to *compare* them you should be aware that rowversion is apparently stored big-endian, so you need to do something like:

```
byte[] timestampByteArray = ... // from datareader/linq2sql etc...
var timestampInt = BitConverter.ToInt64(timestampByteArray, 0);
timestampInt = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(timestampInt);
```

It'd probably be more correct to convert it as ToUInt64, but then you'd have to write your own endian conversion as there's no overload on NetworkToHostOrder that takes uint64. [Or just borrow one](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) from Jon Skeet (search page for 'endian').