# Using converted membership GUID type UserIds in other tables for recognizing rows related to a particular user

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, sql-server

I am using ASP.NET GUID's to identify users uniquely. To identify particular data in other tables, I want to use integer userids. What I am doing is converting the generated GUID's to bigint. Here's how I am converting:

```
select UserId, CONVERT(bigint, convert(varbinary(16) , aspnet_Users.UserId , 1) ) as ConvertedUserId from aspnet_Users
```

And here is the converted result:

```
UserId                                  ConvertedUserId
DFFE5143-AB21-4E57-A033-062833FC69A8    -6903167034088199768
B1D60EDA-30AE-4293-812A-5D71F723B751    -9139389749735999663
EB3E5271-C9CE-437C-9A6C-7D72AFAC4FF4    -7319337362856849420
8984399F-0626-47AA-9CFC-B4F59A08BEDC    -7134628742717456676
71698EC1-9829-478C-AB32-E222C65AE31B    -6110573105403731173
```

So I have three questions:

1. Why they are converted to negative ids?
2. Will conversion always be unique?
3. If they can be converted to positive ids will there be a scenario like a userid is generated in future and its positive conversion may match previously converted userid's positive conversion?

Comment: MySQL is not SQL Server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cast rowversion to bigint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039269/cast-rowversion-to-bigint)

Answer (score 0):

The maximum value of a GUID would be FFFFFFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFF-FFFFFFFFFFFF which is roughly 4.95176015714E+27 . According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx, the max value would be 9,223,372,036,854,775,807. So you cannot convert them, it won't fit.

The first bit of a number denotes if it is a positive or a negative number, if you outgrow a positive field, it will become negative.

If you really wish to use number, i'd create a table in the database, with two fields: a numeric value (int, or int64 if you like), and a guid. That way, you won't have to convert, and you can neatly get to the right unique user.